# what's the preferred visibility toggle for UIImage (like setHidden on UIButton)?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to control visibility on a simple UI element. If it was a button, I'd just call setHiden on it, but UIImage has no such method.

What's the preferred way of showing or hiding an image? Just making it a UIButton and not hooking it up to any methods seems wasteful.. is that really the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your image be in an image view?

`UIImageView imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];`

Then you can hide the image view with:

`imageView.hidden = YES;`

Comment: Ah, this was actually just a dumb mistake on my part. I was doing it all in IB, and mistakenly thought I was adding a UIImage when I was really adding a UIImageView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*hidden* is a property of UIView, so you can use it with UIImageViews.